# Query builder join raw (postgres / postgis)

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, postgis

Is it possible to do this query in Laravel query builder?

```
SELECT table2.id FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON ST_Intersects(table2.geom,table1.geom)
WHERE table1.id = 1234
```

I have tried to search in Laravel doc (Advanced Join Clauses) but I couldn't find any example that fit my problem.

```
$query = Table1::query()
    ->select('table2.id')
    ->join(...)
    ->where('table1.id','=',1234)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution:

```
$query = Table1::query()
    ->select('table2.id')
    ->join('table2', function ($query) {  
        $query->where(\DB::raw('ST_Intersects(table2.geom,table1.geom)'), true);
    })
    ->where('table1.id','=',1234)
    ->get();
```